# IndexError: iterate string on for loop and place character by index

Tags: python, python-3.x

guys I'm **beginner** at the coding. I can't find answer anywhere where I do mistake. it turns `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` all the time.

```
a = 'banana' 
lis = ['_ '* len(a)]

for i,ch in enumerate(a):
        lis[i] = ch
print(lis)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = ['_ '* len(a)]
```

makes a one-element `list` containing a string `2*len(a)` characters long. Thus, `lis[i]` for any `i` aside from `0` is invalid. Presumably you meant to do something like:

```
lis = ['_ '] * len(a)
```

which would make `lis` have the same length as `a`.

That said, the best solution for making a `list` of the characters in `a` is just:

```
lis = list(a)
```

`str` are iterables of their characters (length 1 `str`s themselves), and `list`'s constructor can convert any iterable to a `list`, so that's the simplest solution, no need for `enumerate`, no need to presize a `list` and reassign elements in it at all.